Light steady strobe from broken white lights
When I drive around town, I see white lights steadily flashing when they are broken. Around 1 Hz or maybe up to 5 Hz; different lights at different frequencies. Back in the day, I don't remember seeing steady flashing. I remember yellower lights would flicker. Why do these white lights flash at a steady rate?

Probably LED vs. Sodium vapour lamps, and some failure mode with the power supply or the darkness sensor/remote control.

which lights are you talking about?

Those are likely LED lights with a worn out electrolytic cap in their power supply, which makes the supply to start up but incapable of running the load so it shuts down and after things are settled it tries to start up again. Perfectly normal failure mode.
